# How to make service for uploading files in angular?

Tags: angular, file-upload

I want to make uploading form for plural files

this is component's HTML code

```
    <div
  class="file-input cursor"
  [class.pointer]="!disabled"
  appFileChooser
  (filesChange)="handleFiles($event)"
  accept="*"
  [multiple]="true"
  [disabled]="disabled"
>upload
</div>
```

this is handleFiles function of component ts file

```
  handleFiles(files: File[]): void {
    const file = files[0];
    console.log(files)

    this.uploadService.upload(file).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.image = res.url;
    });
  }
```

this is upload method of uploadService ts file

```
upload(file: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', file);

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', formData);
  }
```

How can I modify this method to support plural files?

Comment: change `upload` to take `update(files: File[])`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
I solved it by creating an array of files.
I used an object with a key and a value, and then before submitting the form the I simply made a for loop like this:

```
for (let file of files) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(file.key, file.value);
}
```